# CGO - undefined reference to '...' when c files are in subfolder

Tags: c, gcc, go, cgo

I have some C files that I have included in my go project using cgo. When they are in the root folder of my go packages, my import looks like this:

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -std=c99 -I .
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gopcua_client.h>
*/
import "C"
```

This builds fine, everything works. However, I want to move the .c and .h files into a subfolder **./include**. I tried this, and changed the import to :

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -std=c99 -I ./include
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gopcua_client.h>
*/
import "C"
```

Now I get an error for every C function I use in the go-file:

```
/tmp/go-build184824875/github.com/coussej/gopcua/_obj/gopcua.cgo2.o: 
In function `_cgo_38ec0a5d28b6_Cfunc_gopcua_read_int32':
./gopcua.go:116: undefined reference to `gopcua_read_int32'
```

I'm not familiar with C, so I'm in the dark here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't specify a relative path, for `./include` because the build happens in a different directory. I haven't tried it with headers and CFLAGS, but can you see if `${SRCDIR}` works? (from the [`cgo` docs](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/))

Comment: When I do that I get: `malformed #cgo argument: -L${SRCDIR}/include`

Comment: Are you using an old version of Go?

Comment: 1.4.2. I'll try updating first.

Comment: `${SRCDIR}` is in go1.5

Comment: Same reference error.  `#cgo CFLAGS: -std=c99 -I${SRCDIR}/include
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/include`

Comment: You should use double quotes (`"`) around includes that are not in the standard system directories, not angle brackets. (some compilers will complain for you). Have you built the shared libs? Go will build C code in the package directory for you, but if you move that code, Go doesn't see it. You can see the compiler invocations with the `-x` option. It's probably best to just keep the code in the package directory if you're not sure what you're doing.

Comment: What @JimB said in his latest comment. In C, `#include "rightHere.h"` means look for the named path relative to the location of the compilation unit, whereas `#include <standardHeaderOverThere.h>` means look in an implementation-defined set of locations.

Comment: I have run the `go build -x` as you suggested, then I get this output. The subfolder is actually included... http://dumptext.com/AEl35q2p

Comment: @coussej: I meant run the build command with `-x` with the files in the same directory so you can see what it does when it works. Have you compiled the libraries in `include/`? -- This is not going to do that for you. You are either missing the compiled .so files, or you need tell the linker to link them specifically, or both.

Comment: How do I compile the files in the include folder? `ggc -std=c99 gopcua_client.c -o gopcua_client.o` ? Sorry for these stupid questions, just no experience with C at all. `go build` mostly just works :-)